# Grab js+flv video without embed option

Tags: video, javascript, flash, scraping

I'm running a website for a political organization and was asked to post this article to the blog along with the embedded video:  http://weareaustin.com/fulltext/?nxd_id=135746

I couldn't figure out a way to get the video from the news page to the client's blog.  Does anyone know an easy way of doing this?

Comment: You are probably better off asking on webmasters.stackexchange.com. Also, while it should be possible to download the video, flash player, and supporting Javascript (after all, that's what your browser does), whether it's a good idea to import that content wholesale into another site is a reasonable question as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ah cool, I wasn't aware that webmasters existed.  And yeah, I see what you're saying about lifting the content.  But it's for a small, non-profit site and will only be seen by a handful of people, so I don't think it's a big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, annoying but simple ways of getting the video include looking through your browser's cache (this may be easier if you clear the cache before visiting the page and loading the video) or running a packet sniffer while you load the video to find out the URL of the video. Once you have the video, you can use your own flash player, or peek at the source of the page to figure out how it plays the video.